# How to change the configuration of a JSP page so that it does not use https anymore?

Tags: jsp, tomcat7

I want to implement Tomcat SSL configuration for all JSP pages that are under "checkout" folder. But rest of the pages should use http only. But the problem is that once the user navigates to checkout page all the non-checkout pages also start using "https" instead of "http". I have done all the necessary configration work which is shown below. Not able to find out the problem. Please guide.

## Tomcat Configuration

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
    maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
    keystoreFile="C:\istore.mvc1.keystore" 
    keystorePass="changeIt" />
```

## web.xml configuration

```
   <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>mycheckout</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/jsp/secure/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

## index.jsp

```
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World! - Non-checkout page</h1><br/>
        <!-- Jump to checkout.jsp and use https (Works fine) -->
        <a href="jsp/secure/checkout.jsp">Go to checkout</a>
    </body>
```

## jsp/secure/checkout.jsp

```
    <body>
        <h1>Checkout starts here!</h1>
        <!-- Jumps to index.jsp but instead of "http" it uses "https" (DOES NOT WORK AS EXPECTED)  -->
        <a href="../../index.jsp">Back to Non-checkout page</a>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that "../../index.jsp" is a relative path so the browser resolves the  address using the location of the jsp/secure/checkout.jsp page that uses https.

Try using an absolute path instead.